# BCB6: How to put elements of a form in an array?

Tags: arrays, c++builder, element

I'm building a simple game in C++Builder6 and I have 42 Image objects on a Form... At start-up I want all Image objects to be disabled, so I wonder can I put all of them in an array and simply loop thorough the entire array and make them Disabled? I know there must be a way, but I'm just new to programming :)

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.
First: You can declare

```
Image* array[40];
```

And dynamically construct the image.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 40; ++i ) {
    image[i] = new Image(this); // where "this" is pointer to your form
    image[i]->Parent = this;

    // option below are optional
    image[i]->Height = 50;
    image[i]->Width = 50;
    image[i]->Left = 40;
    image[i]->Top = 100;
    image[i]->Tag = i;
    image[i]->OnClick = ButtonClick; // connect with method
}
```

Second option is declare

```
Image* array[40];
```

and manually set all values;

```
array[0] = Image1;
...
array[39] = Image40;
```

Then you will have all image in array and you can use loop for doing something on all Image